# How to have Excel Auto Populate Data from a Table when an Option from Drop Down Box is Selected?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to create a form in Excel that auto-fills data when a certain selection is chosen from a drop-down list.

I have the table:

> Apple     | Red 
>  Orange    | Orange
>   Banana    | Yellow
>   Watermelon|
>   Green

I have created a drop down box that has each of the fruits and when I select that fruit I want different cell to fill the color.

I tried using the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(D6,A1:B4,2)
```

But it did not seem to work (when I selected "Apple" it showed "Yellow" in the cell).

Any suggestions on how can I make this work?

Comment: You need to force an exact match in [`VLOOKUP()`](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-vlookup-function). Add ",FALSE" (without the quotes) after the 2.  Click the link to read about `VLOOKUP()`.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula:    `=VLOOKUP(E1,A:B,2,FALSE)`

[image]